# Let $f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ then is $f'(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am a little stuck here, suppose we have some function 
$$f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$ then is $$f'(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)$$ assuming $f$ is differentiable for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

I have this wrote down but I can't remember where it came from and I want to know if that is the case, I took to google but couldn't find anything.

Comment: That is correct. In $f'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} (f(z+h)-f(z))/h$, take $h$ to vary along the real axis.

Comment: Okay thanks, that is where the Cauchy-Riemann equations come from I think I am seeing the light now! So in general is that the best way to figure out the derivative just write the functions $u,v$ and take their partials w.r.t $x$? And if you have a function like $f(z)=f(x+iy)=y+iy^2$ then $f'(z)$ would be zero since the partials w.r.t $x$ are zero?

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations come from comparing the previous limit for $h$ on the real axis with the limit for $h$ on the imaginary axis. The function you wrote down is not a complex-differentiable function, because it doesn't satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Okay I see now but if a function is differentiable then you can just differentiate each part w.r.t $x$?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. If the limit defining $f'(z)$ exists as $h \to 0$ ranging among complex numbers, then this limit will be the same as the limit when $h \to 0$ ranging among real numbers.